# drupal 6: file upload in form not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to have a simple form with a file upload, but it isn;t working. when I check form_state both in the validate and in the submit callbacks, the file value is missing. also check $_FILES and there's nothing.

here is the code I'm using in _form:

```
$form['file'] = array(
      '#type' => 'file',
      '#title' => 'Photo',
    );
```

this is what i'm doing in submit:

```
$validators = array();
    $file = file_save_upload('file', $validators, '/sites/default/files');
    file_set_status($file, FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT);
    krumo ($file);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need specify `$form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data');` apart from your other fields to make it working. See [here](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/file-uploads-drupal-6-part-1) for details.